# Remove .php and id from url and replace with slash

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have tried lots of for url rewrite rules in htaccess but i am stuck now. i have to change this url

```
products.php?id=31
```

to

```
products/31
```

i have used

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   # Turn mod_rewrite on
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

  ## don't touch /forum URIs
  RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

  ## hide .php extension snippet

  # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

  # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

using this i get the following result:

```
products?id=31
```

But this isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your complete `.htaccess` like this:

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  # Turn mod_rewrite on
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  ## don't touch /forum URIs
  RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+products(?:\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ products/%1? [R,L]

  RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

  ## hide .php extension snippet
  # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

  # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: i get this products?id=31  but i need products/31

Comment: For `css/js` just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: if i have to do with .htaccess because in website lots of pages available so

Comment: Ok try this rule: `RewriteRule ^products/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: hello sir i really thanks for you, now i have www.aaaa.com/products/some_product_name i want to replace product with tiles.. than what i have to do ??

Comment: How do you want rewrite `/products/someproductname`? I mean what should be the actual internal URL for `/products/someproductname`?

Comment: i have /products/some_product_name and i need /tiles/some_product_name where some_product_name is dynamic

Comment: So now when you open `http://domain.com/tiles/some_product_name` does it show correct content to you?

Comment: Ok add this rule as **your first rule** `RewriteRule ^products/(.+)$  /tiles/$1 [NC,R,L]`

Comment: ALso may I request to create new questions in future rather than askin g new questions via comments. These comments can be deleted anytime by moderators.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use it like that

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)$ products.php?id=$1
```

Comment: can i see how you did it please

Answer (score 0):

use below htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]*)$ /product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```