# Remove ?id= from URL

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove ?id= from the url and replace ?id= with a slash (/).

I want to show the address:
`https://localhost/Test/Change.php?id=sd32sdas93ks93kf.553sa`

As:
`https://localhost/Test/Change/sd32sdas93ks93kf.553sa`

I have managed to delete the `.php` from the URL, but I have still issues with `?id=`

The original link with `?id=` accessible. When I navigate to the page without `?id=` I get:
`The requested URL Test/Change/sd32sdas93ks93kf.553sa.php` was not found on this Server`.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Change(?:\.php)?\?id=([a-z\-_0-9]+)/([^/.]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^Change/%1? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^Change/([a-z\-_0-9]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ Change.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php and id from url and replace with slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738855/remove-php-and-id-from-url-and-replace-with-slash)

Comment: @P.Dev Why do you think my question is a duplicate? I am using the 'same code'. In my case the code is not working.

Comment: Rewrite log, END flag, and perhaps some reading of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: In the article I see the same thing. It is still not clear what I am doing wrong and why my script is not working